# use textFieldDidEndEditing textfield delegate to find 3 element in array

Tags: arrays, swift, sequence, uitextfielddelegate

My swift code below uses UITextFieldDelegate in textfield var enterT. nameString converts a core data entity to the array of strings, like [bob,bryan,jessica]. In textFieldDidEndEditing, I want the user to be able to enter any number, e.g 3 and third element from the array to be printed and then sort the array.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet var labelName : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var enterT : UITextField!

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate //Singlton instance
var context:NSManagedObjectContext!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    openDatabse()




}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard let index = Int(textField.text!) else {
        // display an alert about invalid text
        return
    }
    joke(at: index)
}

func joke(at index : Int) {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "idx == %d", Int32(index))
    do {
        if let user = try context.fetch(fetchRequest).first {
            print(user.username)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not fetch \(error) ")
    }
}


func openDatabse()
{
    context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Users", in: context)
    let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    let newUser2 = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    let newUser3 = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    saveData(UserDBObj: newUser, UserDBObj2: newUser2, UserDBObj3: newUser3)

}

func saveData(UserDBObj:NSManagedObject,UserDBObj2:NSManagedObject,UserDBObj3:NSManagedObject)
{
    UserDBObj.setValue("kim kardashian", forKey: "username")
    UserDBObj2.setValue("jessica biel", forKey: "username")
    UserDBObj3.setValue("Hailey Rienhart", forKey: "username")




    print("Storing Data..")
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Storing data Failed")
    }

    fetchData()
}

func fetchData()
{
    print("Fetching Data..")
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            let userName = data.value(forKey: "username") as! String

            print("User Name is : "+userName)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Fetching data Failed")
    }
}}
```

[image: gif of what I am looking for]

Comment: Do you ever read my comments? Core Data saves the records **unordered**, the order of `result` is random. To associate a record with a fixed index you have to add an `index` attribute to the Core Data model. Then you are able to fetch the corresponding record by `index`.

Comment: @vadian I don't know how to do that? Are you talking about click on core data model. Click on attribute and then click on index in spotlight.

Comment: No, I mean to add an attribute `index` (name it as you like) as `Int32` next to `username`.

Comment: @vadian did that added a photo above. What should I don now.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the entered number to `Int`. If this succeeds pass the integer to `joke` and fetch the record matching the `idx` attribute.

Consider that indexes start with zero. If you want to enter numbers starting with one you have to decrement the index (`joke(at: index - 1)`)

```
@IBOutlet var enterT : UITextField!

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard let index = Int(textField.text!) else { 
      // display an alert about invalid text
      return 
    }
    joke(at: index)
}

func joke(at index : Int) {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "idx == %d", Int32(index))
    do {
        if let user = try context.fetch(fetchRequest).first {
            print(user.username)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not fetch \(error) ")
    }
}
```

Note: I recommend to define `idx` and `username` as non-optional in the Core Data model. And make sure that all `idx` values are unique.

Comment: I added all of my code above it compiles but it has not effect when a user enters a number in textfield enterT.

Comment: I added a gif of what I am looking for. Thanks for your help so far.